# modifying the dplyr output for selected variables

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have to calculate the frequency, mean, sd for each variable in `varb` based on the `cat1` groups. The below code works fine as required.

```
# Random generation of values for categorical data
set.seed(33)
df <- data.frame(cat1 = sample( LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE ), 
                cat2 = sample( LETTERS[3:5], 100, replace=TRUE ),
                cat3 = sample( LETTERS[2:4], 100, replace=TRUE ),
                con1 = runif(100,0,100),
                con2 = runif(100,23,45),
                con3 = runif(100,55,100),
                con4 = runif(100,12,49))

# Introducing null values 
df$con1[c(23,53,92)] <- NA
df$con2[c(33,46)] <- NA
df$con3[c(59,72)] <- NA
df$con4[c(33,46)] <- NA

# Selecting the variables of interest
varb <- c("con1","con2","con3","con4")

# Calculating the stats
results <- df %>% group_by(cat1) %>% summarise_each(funs(count=sum(!is.na(.)),
                                                              mean(., na.rm = TRUE),
                                                              sd(., na.rm = TRUE)),
                                                         one_of(varb))
#Output    
> results
    Source: local data frame [2 x 13]

      cat1 con1_count con2_count con3_count con4_count con1_mean con2_mean con3_mean con4_mean  con1_sd  con2_sd  con3_sd  con4_sd
    1    A         50         51         50         51   45.0175  34.24199  77.95732  30.84059 29.41333 6.327222 13.13494 11.53573
    2    B         47         47         48         47   46.6868  33.30931  81.14928  28.14640 25.80322 6.909720 11.93321 10.04867
```

I would like to apply the same functions on each variable in `varb2`(which was part of `varb`) for the `df[which(df$cat2 == 'D'),]` subset data in addition to the previous `cat1` grouping. The below piece of code does that.

```
# Selecting the variables of interest
varb2 <- c("con2","con4")

# Calculating the stats
results2 <- df[which(df$cat2 == 'D'),] %>% group_by(cat1) %>% summarise_each(funs(count=sum(!is.na(.)),
                                                              mean(., na.rm = TRUE),
                                                              sd(., na.rm = TRUE)),
                                                         one_of(varb2))
# Output
results2
Source: local data frame [2 x 7]

  cat1 con2_count con4_count con2_mean con4_mean  con2_sd   con4_sd
1    A         13         13  36.08892  30.28429 7.172574 14.308223
2    B         13         13  31.83272  28.24502 6.497423  8.763573
```

I would like to modify the first output `results` with the new output `results2` for each variable in `varb2`.Could you please provide suggestions to modify the output instead of removing the `varb2` from `varb` from the task ?

```
# Expected Output
Source: local data frame [2 x 13]

  cat1 con1_count con2_count con3_count con4_count con1_mean con2_mean con3_mean con4_mean  con1_sd  con2_sd  con3_sd  con4_sd
1    A         50         13         50         13   45.0175  36.08892  77.95732  30.28429 29.41333 7.172574 13.13494 14.308223
2    B         47         13         48         13   46.6868  31.83272  81.14928  28.24502 25.80322 6.497423 11.93321 8.763573
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do? I find it hard to understand

Comment: @docendodiscimus Does it make sense now ?

Comment: What do you mean by "[...] modify the output instead of removing the varb2 from varb from the task ?" do you want to use filter in the pipe?

Comment: @Paul4forest I want to update the `results2` values in `results` output.

Comment: So for con1 and con3, you want to calculate the summary for any values in cat2. But for con2 and con4, you only want to calculate the summary for values in cat2 == "D".

Comment: exactly, as a single output !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new data frame in which you replace the values you don't want to summarise by NA.

```
df2 <- df
df2[df2$cat2!="D",varb2] <- NA
results3 <- df2 %>% 
    group_by(cat1) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(count=sum(!is.na(.)),
                        mean(., na.rm = TRUE),
                        sd(., na.rm = TRUE)),
                   one_of(varb))
```

You might also have worked with data reshaped in long format.

```
library(reshape2)
results4 <- df %>% 
    melt(id = c("cat1","cat2","cat3")) %>%
    # con1 and con3, can have any values in cat2.
    # for con2 and con4, you only want 
    # to calculate the summary for values in cat2 == "D". 
    filter((!variable %in% varb2) |
               (variable %in% varb2 & cat2 == "D")) %>%
    group_by(cat1,variable) %>%
    summarise(count = sum(!is.na(value)),
              mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),
              sd = sd(value, na.rm = TRUE))

# Which you could always reshape again
results4 %>% 
    rename(con = variable) %>%
    melt(id = c("cat1", "con")) %>%
    dcast(cat1 ~ con + variable)
```

The tidyr package can also reshape data, (I'm not yet used to it) see the [R Studio data wrangling cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, I have already achieved this with the last command posted in the question. I would like to update these values in `results`. I will include the example in the question. Thanks !

Comment: I've edited the answer and added another way to do calculate summaries by reshaping your data in long format.